# calculate anti clockwise angle between 2 points

Tags: python, numpy, atan2

I have a robot with red led and green led mounted at the front and back respectively. I want to calculate the head direction of the robot as in which direction is the greenLEd - redLed vector pointed to.

How can I code it such that the points marked 1 and 2 in the image below have the same angle i.e. 45degree anti-clockwise whereas point 3 should be at 225degrees.

[image]

I used the following script but it giving me wrong results:

```
def headDirectionAngle(redLEDCoords, greenLEDCoords, referenceVector):
    greenRedLEDVector = np.array(greenLEDCoords) - np.array(redLEDCoords)
    angle = np.math.atan2(np.linalg.det([referenceVector,greenRedLEDVector]),np.dot(referenceVector,greenRedLEDVector))
    return np.degrees(angle)
referenceVector = np.array([0,240])
```

How should I proceed? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's your goal with this vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back to basics, without `numpy`.

[`atan2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.atan2) already gives you an anticlockwise angle, but between -180 and 180. You can add 360 and calculate modulo 360 to get an angle between 0 and 360:

```
from math import atan2, degrees

def anti_clockwise(x,y):
    alpha = degrees(atan2(y,x))
    return (alpha + 360) % 360

print(anti_clockwise(480, 480))
# 45.0
print(anti_clockwise(-480, -480))
# 225.0
```

`x` should just be the difference in X coordinates between the green and red LEDs. Same goes for `y`.

Comment: atan2 gives you angle wrt horizontal axis. Is there any way I can update it to calculate the angle wrt a vector?

Comment: @deathracer: you can calculate te angle wrt horizontal axis for both vectors, and calculate the difference.